# SSR with PCB design improvements

Tags: pcb, relay, design, solid-state-relay, diy

I have worked on this project of my own so I need to confirm that it will work
Its a simple SSR with max. current rating of 20A (normal use will be around 13A)
I use 40A TRIAC just for safe side(also its available) Input voltage is 5V DC Output voltage is 230V AC
I want to know about PCB trace width for R2 and R3 (my understanding is that they will not face more than 1A current so I use 0.5 mm trace width..is it ok?)
For 20A current I use 5 mm trace width with 20°C temperature rise (calculators show 6 mm)
Are these trace widths work?
Also can someone tell me how I can use NPN transistor with resistor to get range of input voltage?[image]

[image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: "DC Output voltage" are you sure? Please use punctuation to convey ideas clearly, thanks :) || You may also want more separation (clearance and creepage) distance between the isolated side, particularly the trace to connector pin 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be extra sure you can specify 2oz copper. For 230V, you could also put a hole in the PCB in case you need to strap a wire.

Comment: ofcourse the calculation of 6 mm trace width is based on 2 oz

Comment: I use 5 mm because I also use a cooling fan for heat dissipation

Comment: My confusion is with R2 and R3 trace widths...Is 0.5 mm enough for them?

Comment: You're fine on current, but maybe make those planes and separate them a little bit more.

Comment: When the isolator is enabled, current flowing through R2+R3 is less than 1A through either of those resistors. However, looks like you have plenty of space to use 40 mil lines and double it up.